# why doesn't work this example

Tags: java, android, physics

I am new to game development.

I was trying to use this http://blog.gemserk.com/2012/07/03/drawing-a-projectile-trajectory-like-angry-birds-using-libgdx/  projectile example in eclipse android using java language

What mistake did I make? How to do.

Here my code:

```
import android.content.Context;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;

import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;

import android.graphics.Canvas;

import android.util.Log;

import android.view.MotionEvent;

import android.view.SurfaceView;

import android.view.View;

import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector2;


public class Example extends SurfaceView {

public float x;
public float y;

public static class ProjectileEquation {

    public float gravity = -10;
    public Vector2 startVelocity = new Vector2();

    public Vector2 startPoint = new Vector2();

    public float getX(float t) {
        return startVelocity.x * t + startPoint.x;

    }

    public float getY(float t) {
        return 0.5f * gravity * t * t + startVelocity.y * t + startPoint.y;
    }
    {
        Log.i("ProjectileEquation", "Create!");
    }

}

public static class Controller {

    public float power = 50f;
    public float angle = 0f;

}


public Example(Context context) {
    super(context);
    Log.i("Example constructor ", "Create!");
    Example.projectile yyy = new Example.projectile(context);
    Log.i("run", "Create!");
    this.x = yyy.x;
    this.y = yyy.y;
}


@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    super.onTouchEvent(event);

{
        Log.i("OnTouch", "Create!");
    }

    x = event.getX();
    y = event.getY();

    return true;

}

public static class projectile extends View {
    public float x;
    public float y;
    private Controller controller;
    private ProjectileEquation projectileEquation;

    public int trajectoryPointCount = 30;
    public float timeSeparation = 1f;

    private Bitmap bmp;

    public projectile(Context context) {
        super(context);
        Log.i("Projectile constructor ", "Create!");
        this.controller = new Controller();
        this.projectileEquation = new ProjectileEquation();
        this.projectileEquation.gravity = -10;
        bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                R.drawable.ic_launcher);

           {
            projectileEquation.startVelocity.set(controller.power, 0f);
            projectileEquation.startVelocity.rotate(controller.angle);

        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        float t = 0f;

        float width = this.getWidth();
        float height = this.getHeight();

        float timeSeparation = this.timeSeparation;

        for (int i = 0; i < trajectoryPointCount; i++) {
            float x = this.x + projectileEquation.getX(t);
            float y = this.y + projectileEquation.getY(t);

            canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, x, y, null);
            canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, width, height, null);
            t += timeSeparation;

        }
    }

}
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with it? Is there some error? If so, what is it?

Comment: OnDraw() is not run

Comment: Your code looks ill-formated, you have some code that is outside of functions ( or you have not pasted it properly ) - that's why it won't compile. Also, now Google endorses [Android Studio](http://developer.android.com/tools/studio/index.html) instead of Eclipse.